# Docker error at build E: Release file for http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/dists/bookworm-security/InRelease is not valid yet

Tags: php, docker, debian, docker-build

I have Arch Linux and I installed docker today, the issue is that when I want to build the container of my project it gives me this error, I tried building it on my other computer and it works without problem.

```bash
CIFweb on  deploy is  v1.0.0 via  v20.11.1 via  
❯ docker buildx build -t phppinarmvc:1 .  
                        
[+] Building 3.5s (5/12)                                                                                                                                                     docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 557B                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/php:8.2-apache                                                                                                                      0.8s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [1/9] FROM docker.io/library/php:8.2-apache@sha256:3a2cdc2bd1b62f572d5f8abfc8c069d5bceba0871fb088ebc3f1313ae35dbf75                                                         0.0s
 => ERROR [2/9] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y     libfreetype6-dev     libjpeg62-turbo-dev     libpng-dev                                                                   2.7s
------                                                                                                                                                                                      
 > [2/9] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y     libfreetype6-dev     libjpeg62-turbo-dev     libpng-dev:                                                                              
0.451 Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease [151 kB]                                                                                                                        
0.751 Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease [55.4 kB]                                                                                                               
0.850 Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease [48.0 kB]                                                                                                     
0.948 Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages [8786 kB]                                                                                                             
1.840 Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates/main amd64 Packages [12.7 kB]
2.376 Reading package lists...
2.655 E: Release file for http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/dists/bookworm-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 4h 34min 44s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
------
Dockerfile:3
--------------------
   2 |     
   3 | >>> RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
   4 | >>>     libfreetype6-dev \
   5 | >>>     libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
   6 | >>>     libpng-dev
   7 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y     libfreetype6-dev     libjpeg62-turbo-dev     libpng-dev" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.2-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/public/images/
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/public/images/
RUN chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/public/images/

VOLUME /var/www/html
VOLUME /usr/local/etc/php
VOLUME /etc/apache2/sites-available
```

I got it to work with this command but it's not what I want.

[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wA5lr.png)